# Heroku upload react app show cannot access '/app/build/static/js/*.js': No such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I built react app and upload it to heroku.
i add create-react-app-buildpack.git into heroku
[image]

I get error

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command

then I run heroku logs --tail in my project and get

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.3",
    "npm": "6.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.2.3",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^6.1.0",
    "bfj": "6.1.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "chalk": "2.4.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "6.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.5",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt": "0.4.14",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "icheck": "^1.0.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "23.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "mobx": "^5.6.0",
    "mobx-persist": "^0.4.1",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.2",
    "mobx-react-router": "^4.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.0.6",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "rc-time-picker": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^0.1.3",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.20.2",
    "react-datepicker": "1.6.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^6.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-icheck": "^0.3.8",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.2",
    "react-ladda": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-select": "^2.1.2",
    "react-switchery-component": "^0.0.7",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "react-toastify": "^4.4.3",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "resolve": "1.8.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "url-loader": "1.1.1",
    "validatorjs": "^3.15.1",
    "webpack": "4.19.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.9",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js",
    "heroku-prebuild": "export NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false; export NODE_ENV=; NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false NODE_ENV=development npm install --only=dev --dev",
    "heroku-postbuild": "export NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true; export NODE_ENV=production;"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
        {
          "legacy": true
        }
      ],
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        {
          "loose": true
        }
      ]
    ],
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```